# How to use root.after in two function Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have the code below the issue with it is that when i choose "Fahrenheit" it runs the second function then it goes back and run the first function too. I want it to run one function if the condition it met I m thinking that root.after is what causing the issue but I m not sure how to fix it.

I m using this script to display the temperature of my server and update it periodically and I want to create a drop to change the value from Celsius to Fahrenheit.

```
from tkinter import *

import paramiko

root = Tk()
root.title('Raspberry Temperature')
root.geometry("250x250")

lab = Label(root)
lab.pack(pady=10)
lab.place(x=140, y=15)

label1 = Label(root, text="Core Temperature :", font=('Segoe', 10))
label1.pack(pady=10)
label1.place(x=20, y=15)


def temperature():
    global after_id
    p = paramiko.SSHClient()
    p.set_missing_host_key_policy(
        paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())  
    p.connect("pi", port=22, username="user", password="pass")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = p.exec_command("vcgencmd measure_temp")
    opt = stdout.readlines()
    opt = "".join(opt)
    print(opt)
    lab.config(text=opt, font=('Segoe', 11, 'bold'))

    after_id = root.after(1000, temperature)
    return after_id
def temperature2():
    global after_id
    p2 = paramiko.SSHClient()
    p2.set_missing_host_key_policy(
        paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())  # This script doesn't work for me unless this line is added!
    p2.connect("pi", port=22, username="user", password="pass")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = p2.exec_command("vcgencmd measure_temp")
    opt2 = stdout.readlines()
    opt2 = "".join(opt2)
    print(opt2)
    lab.config(text=(opt2,"temp2"), font=('Segoe', 11, 'bold'))

    #
    after_id = root.after(1000, temperature2)
    return after_id

import tkinter as tk

OptionList = [
"fahrenheit",
]

variable = tk.StringVar(root)
variable.set(OptionList[0])

opt = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, *OptionList)
opt.config(width=10, font=('Helvetica', 12))
opt.pack(side="top")
opt.place(x= 10,y=50)

labelTest = tk.Label(text="", font=('Helvetica', 12), fg='red')
labelTest.pack(side="top")

temperature()

def callback(*args):
    global after_id
    after_cancel(after_id)
    temperature2()

variable.trace("w", callback)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `after_cancel(...)` inside `callback()` function should be `root.after_cancel(...)`.

Comment: You can actually just execute `temperature()` periodically and do whatever inside the function based on the selected value of `OptionMenu`.  Then you don't need to cancel the exiting `after()` task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have both `temperature` and `temperature2` in a loop, but you never cancel the loops. So, if you first start the `temperature` loop and then later start the `temperature2` loop, so both loops will be running.

You can stop an existing loop by saving the identifier returned by `after`, and calling `after_cancel` with that identifier.

In your case you probably want to cancel the existing loop inside of `callback`:

```
def callback(*args):
    global after_id
    after_cancel(after_id)
    temperature2()
```

Then, you must also remember to initialize `after_id`. For example:

```
def temperature():
    global after_id
    ...
    after_id = root.after(1000, temperature)
```

Of course, you'll probably want to put some code in to handle the case where after_id isn't defined or calling `after_cancel` failed. The bottom line, however, is that you need to stop any existing loop before starting a new one.

Comment: I changed the code but because I m new with python I m not fully understanding your solution can you see what I'm still missing. I apologize as this is one of my first scripts.